# Too many storage controllers of the type in Vagrant

Tags: virtual-machine, vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I'm going to create 7 servers with 2 disks each. Here is the vagrant file. This is my first configuration of a multiple machines environments. Hence I haven't any experience in creating environments from scratch.

This is the error I got

```
Command: ["storagectl", "cc27c05a-63da-4e02-ab73-86843032e387", "--name", "SATA Controller", "--add", "sata"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: Too many storage controllers of this type
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_INVALID_ARG (0x80070057), component StorageController, interface IStorageController, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "AddStorageController(Bstr(pszCtl).raw(), StorageBus_SATA, ctl.asOutParam())" at line 1044 of file VBoxManageStorageController.cpp
```

**Vagrafile**

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048", "--cpus", "1"]
        vb.customize ["storagectl", :id, "--name", "SATA Controller", "--add", "sata"]
    end

    config.vm.define "machine1" do |machine1|

        machine1.vm.hostname = "machine1"

        machine1.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
            vb.customize ["createhd",  "--filename", "machine1_disk0", "--size", 4096]
            vb.customize ["createhd",  "--filename", "machine1_disk1", "--size", 4096]
            vb.customize ["storageattach", :id, "--storagectl", "SATA Controller", "--port", 1, "--type", "hdd", "--medium", "machine1_disk0.vdi"]
            vb.customize ["storageattach", :id, "--storagectl", "SATA Controller", "--port", 2, "--type", "hdd", "--medium", "machine1_disk1.vdi"]
        end

        machine1.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.10"
        machine1.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.15"
    end

    config.vm.define "machine2" do |machine2|

        machine2.vm.hostname = "machine2"

        machine2.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
            vb.customize ["createhd",  "--filename", "machine2_disk0", "--size", 4096]
            vb.customize ["createhd",  "--filename", "machine2_disk1", "--size", 4096]
            vb.customize ["storageattach", :id, "--storagectl", "SATA Controller", "--port", 1, "--type", "hdd", "--medium", "machine2_disk0.vdi"]
            vb.customize ["storageattach", :id, "--storagectl", "SATA Controller", "--port", 2, "--type", "hdd", "--medium", "machine2_disk1.vdi"]
        end

        machine2.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.20"
        machine2.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.25"
    end

    config.vm.define "machine3" do |machine3|

        machine3.vm.hostname = "machine3"

        machine3.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
            vb.customize ["createhd",  "--filename", "machine3_disk0", "--size", 4096]
            vb.customize ["createhd",  "--filename", "machine3_disk1", "--size", 4096]
            vb.customize ["storageattach", :id, "--storagectl", "SATA Controller", "--port", 1, "--type", "hdd", "--medium", "machine3_disk0.vdi"]
            vb.customize ["storageattach", :id, "--storagectl", "SATA Controller", "--port", 2, "--type", "hdd", "--medium", "machine3_disk1.vdi"]
        end

        machine3.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.30"
    end

    config.vm.define "machine4" do |machine4|

        machine4.vm.hostname = "machine4"

        machine4.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
            vb.customize ["createhd",  "--filename", "machine4_disk0", "--size", 4096]
            vb.customize ["createhd",  "--filename", "machine4_disk1", "--size", 4096]
            vb.customize ["storageattach", :id, "--storagectl", "SATA Controller", "--port", 1, "--type", "hdd", "--medium", "machine4_disk0.vdi"]
            vb.customize ["storageattach", :id, "--storagectl", "SATA Controller", "--port", 2, "--type", "hdd", "--medium", "machine4_disk1.vdi"]
        end

        machine4.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.40"
    end

    config.vm.define "machine5" do |machine5|

        machine5.vm.hostname = "machine5"

        machine5.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
            vb.customize ["createhd",  "--filename", "machine5_disk0", "--size", 4096]
            vb.customize ["createhd",  "--filename", "machine5_disk1", "--size", 4096]
            vb.customize ["storageattach", :id, "--storagectl", "SATA Controller", "--port", 1, "--type", "hdd", "--medium", "machine5_disk0.vdi"]
            vb.customize ["storageattach", :id, "--storagectl", "SATA Controller", "--port", 2, "--type", "hdd", "--medium", "machine5_disk1.vdi"]
        end

        machine5.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.50"
    end

    config.vm.define "machine6" do |machine6|

        machine6.vm.hostname = "machine6"

        machine6.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
            vb.customize ["createhd",  "--filename", "machine6_disk0", "--size", 4096]
            vb.customize ["createhd",  "--filename", "machine6_disk1", "--size", 4096]
            vb.customize ["storageattach", :id, "--storagectl", "SATA Controller", "--port", 1, "--type", "hdd", "--medium", "machine6_disk0.vdi"]
            vb.customize ["storageattach", :id, "--storagectl", "SATA Controller", "--port", 2, "--type", "hdd", "--medium", "machine6_disk1.vdi"]
        end

        machine6.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.60"
    end

    config.vm.define "machine7" do |machine7|

        machine7.vm.hostname = "machine7"

        machine7.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
            vb.customize ["createhd",  "--filename", "machine7_disk0", "--size", 4096]
            vb.customize ["createhd",  "--filename", "machine7_disk1", "--size", 4096]
            vb.customize ["storageattach", :id, "--storagectl", "SATA Controller", "--port", 1, "--type", "hdd", "--medium", "machine7_disk0.vdi"]
            vb.customize ["storageattach", :id, "--storagectl", "SATA Controller", "--port", 2, "--type", "hdd", "--medium", "machine7_disk1.vdi"]
        end

        machine7.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.70"
    end

end
```

Comment: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=56455

Comment: I have already checked out that discussion. When I try to create the SATA Controller I get that error because there is another SATA controller already created in a different virtual machine previously created with vagrant. The weird thing is that it seems that vboxmanage command sees the already existing sata controller as it was a global variable

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your box already have existing SATA storage controller, so you shouldn't try to add new one in the beginning of your provision (you cannot add multiple SATA storage controllers).

Comment: It doesn't have any Sata controller yet. This error is caused by the fact that already exist a vagrant vm previously created which have a sata controller. The machine I'm going to create it doesn't have any sata controller

Comment: If you are using ubuntu/trusty64 as base image, that machine already comes with SATA controller pre configured.

Comment: Then the problem is that the base image has already a sata controller. A trick to fix the issue is not create any controller but use that already existed. I don't think that could be the problem you say the real problem. Every base image come with a sata controller preexisted

Answer (score 0):

If your box already contains a SATA Controller, you can fix changing controller type to SAS:

```
vb.customize ["storagectl", :id, "--name", "SAS Controller", "--add", "sas", '--portcount', 2]
```

and change controller name reference for every disk you attach to it:

```
vb.customize ["storageattach", :id, "--storagectl", "SAS Controller", "--port", 1, "--type", "hdd", "--medium", "machine7_disk0.vdi"]
```

with SAS controller I solved this issues in vagrant and virtualbox.